# SQL, How to put incremental row number during append?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have table in which i have data like

```
date       id   $   row_nmbr
1/1/2016    A   40  1
1/2/2016    A   40  2
1/3/2016    A   40  3
1/1/2016    B   40  1
1/2/2016    B   40  2
```

This is working fine when i insert a new set of data, But when i insert data for a existing combination i am getting the row number back to 1.

**new data**

```
date        id  $   
1/4/2016    A   40
```

When is insert it i want it to get inserted like

```
date       id   $   row_nmbr
1/1/2016    A   40  1
1/2/2016    A   40  2
1/3/2016    A   40  3
1/4/2016    A   40  4<--- New data
1/1/2016    B   40  1
1/2/2016    B   40  2
```

Help on how this can be achieved during next inserts

Comment: See the section about secondary keys in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't worry about it. This kind of problem is often indicative of a fundamental flaw in your design/your understanding of relational data (within the context of an RDBMS).

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add back the appropriate tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

This will increase the row numbers for existing ids and start with one for new ids:

```
insert into target_table
select src.date, src.id, src.$, 
   row_number() over (partition by src.id order by src.date)
     -- existing number or zero for new ids
   + coalesce(row_nmbrs.max_row_nmbr, 0)
from source_table as src
left join 
 ( -- current row numbers for each id
   select id, max(row_nmbr) as max_row_nmbr
   from target_table
   group by 1
 ) as row_nmbrs
on src.id = row_nmbrs.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Table(date, id, `$`, row_nmbr)
  select '01-04-2016', 'A', 40, coalesce(max(row_nmbr),0)+1
    from Table
   where id='A'
```

Comment: will it work if i have new records for both A and B?

Comment: @Kaleem Yes. then the implicit "group by", it always returns one row. `max()` returns NULL. `coalesce()` turn into 0. 0+1=1